# Obtain the result in easier way

Tags: c#

I need to get an array containing reversed alternate elements of the original array.

For example: an array containing elements {12,56,67}.

I need to get an array containing {67,12}
(reversing array to get {67,56,12} then take alternate elements means {67,12})

I need to do this in c#

Comment: We can, but shouldn't you be doing your homework yourself?

Comment: I need an alternateway thats why.

Comment: Well, tell us the slow, non-optimized, non-"user driven" (whatever the heck that means), and we can tell you improvements.

Comment: The guy is asking for help, why are people voting the question down? If you don't want to help, don't - but don't vote the guy down for asking.

Comment: I tightened up the question and title and made it readable plus added the beginner tag. I was tempted to add 'homework' but didn't

Comment: People should be honest about their intentions in posting here.

Comment: Peter I'll not edit war it with you but you took it from a meaningful title to a non meaningful one. English would appear not to be your first language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# 3, try this:

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
var x = array.Reverse().Where( (n,i) => i % 2 !=0);
```

Where is an extension method (new in C# 3.0) which forms part of a language feature called LINQ. It filters a sequence based on a predicate.  In the sample above, n is the element of the sequence and i is the zero based index of the element in the sequence. Both are strongly typed. The predicate i%2!=0 is saying that the index of the element is not directly divisible by 2, so what we are saying is reverse the list and select the odd elements from it.

Not the most efficient solution, but short and concise.

Comment: Where( ( n, i ) => i % 2 != 0 ),,what here happening,,n and i not declaring datatype,then also

Comment: this is working fine in online of code,,Can you tell me every thing ,,iam abeginner i need to study everything,,what is Var key word here,,i saw these things in LINQ query

Comment: I've added an explanation in the answer above, hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This won't be the shortest answer you'll get, but it seems fairly optimised to me.

```
int[] rgIn = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5};

int[] rgOut = new int[rgIn.Length / 2];

int ixOut = 0;
for (int ixIn = rgIn.Length - 2; ixIn >= 0; ixIn -= 2)
{
    rgOut[ixOut++] = rgIn[ixIn];
}
```